# Brave/Cautious reasoning in clingo

Tags: reasoning, logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

In Clingo guide, there are two modes called cautious and brave introduced as the follows:

> **brave** Compute the brave consequences (union of all answer sets) of a
>   logic program.
>
> **cautious** Compute the cautious consequences (intersection of all answer sets) of a logic program.

No more information is provided in the guide. I tried some examples and have trouble understanding the issue.

I tried to run the following simple ASP program:

```
p :- not q.
q :- not p.
```

Running Clingo with no mode parameter will give the right answer sets:

```
answer 1:{p}
answer 2:{q}
```

As described in the guide, if run under brave mode, which will compute union of all answer sets, I should get the result `{p, q}`.

Similarly, for cautious case, empty result is expected.

However, the actual result for brave reasoning by Clingo is:

> clingo version 5.3.0
>
> Reading from test/cautious_reasoning.lp
>
> Solving...
>
> Answer: 1
>
> q
>
> Consequences: [1;2]
>
> Answer: 2
>
> q p
>
> Consequences: [2;2]
>
> SATISFIABLE
>
> Models       : 2
>
> Brave      : yes
>
> Consequences : 2
>
> Calls        : 1
>
> Time         : 0.006s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
>
> CPU Time     : 0.002s

And for the cautious case:

> clingo version 5.3.0
>
> Reading from test/cautious_reasoning.lp
>
> Solving...
>
> Answer: 1
>
> q
>
> Consequences: [0;1]
>
> Answer: 2
>
> Consequences: [0;0]
>
> SATISFIABLE
>
> Models       : 2
>
> Cautious   : yes
>
> Consequences : 0
>
> Calls        : 1
>
> Time         : 0.001s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
>
> CPU Time     : 0.001s

So what does the numbers in `[]` represent? How to understand the cautious and brave reasoning mode in Clingo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke clingo with enumeration algorithm `--enum-mode brave` or `--enum-mode cautious`, the atoms that appear in each enumerated model "converge" to the set of brave or cautious consequences, resp. That is, in `brave` mode the atoms will monotonically increase, while in `cautious` mode the atoms will monotonically decrease. Think of it as a "running" union or intersection for brave and cautious consequences, resp.

The numbers inside the square brackets `[d;p]` have the following meaning: clingo calls [`TextOutput::printMeta`](https://github.com/potassco/clasp/blob/6382096f5a28c8d30756c105a03d562c8ea72e55/src/clasp_output.cpp#L954) for each model, which prints a pair of integers `[d;p]` of definite consequences `d` and remaining possible consequences `p` as computed by [`Output::numCons`](https://github.com/potassco/clasp/blob/6382096f5a28c8d30756c105a03d562c8ea72e55/src/clasp_output.cpp#L203).

Edit: the last answer will then give you the final result, i.e., the brave/cautious consequences of the input program. If all you care about is the final result, you may invoke clingo like this to get the brave consequences (e.g., of program `a | b | c | d.`):

```sh
% echo 'a|b|c|d.' | clingo -e brave | grep -A1 '^Answer:' | tail -n -1
b c d a
```

And for the cautious consequences of program `a | b | c | d.` (i.e., the empty set), you just need to start clingo in cautious enumeration mode:

```sh
% echo 'a|b|c|d.' | clingo -e cautious | grep -A1 '^Answer:' | tail -n -1
```

Comment: So for the final intersection result of cautious, I should refer to the last answer set and for the union case I should refer to the first one, is that so? If so, all other models can be viewed as intermediate results. Then how are these intermediate results computed and do they have certain meanings or use?

Comment: The last set of atoms will always give you the brave/cautious consequences